# Multiple view click events using nested constraint layout (2.0.0 beta 2)

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I have created my layout with `ConstraintLayout` and as `ConstraintLayout` allows you to build complex layouts without having to nest View. In my case, I want multiple view click events.

I have tried using `Group` as you can get a list of ids that are members of your `Group` in your code and set click listener.

```
 fun Group.setAllOnClickListener(listener: View.OnClickListener?) {
            referencedIds.forEach { id ->
                rootView.findViewById<View>(id).setOnClickListener(listener)
            }
        }
```

However, this does not seem to work as of the `ConstraintLayout` version `2.0.0-beta2`. This code is working till `2.0.0-alpha3`. I have implemented using multiple `ConstraintLayout` so is it alright to use nested constraint layout?

I am using `MotionLayout` and other animation of constraint layout so I can't use a lower version of `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been a change to when a group's referenced ids are available. Before *2.0.0-beta2*, they are  available immediately in `onCreate()`. It seems that with *2.0.0-beta2*, they are only available post-layout. I am not sure if this is documented or if it is just a side-effect.

The following will work for you in *2.0.0-beta2*:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    fun Group.setAllOnClickListener(listener: View.OnClickListener?) {
        referencedIds.forEach { id ->
            rootView.findViewById<View>(id).setOnClickListener(listener)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Referenced ids are not available here but become available post-layout.
        layout.post {
            group.setAllOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(v: View) {
                    val text = (v as Button).text
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is absolutely working with 2.0.0-beta2